# How to convert a char to a boolean in Java?

Tags: java, casting, char, boolean

I would like to display on the screen a question with two options (Are you married: y/n). The user would have to press or "y" or "n". After that I would like to print on the screen "married" or "not-married".

I've thought in using a char to get the input thorough the Scanner class (System.in) and after cast this char to a boolean type in order to display two options with an if statement. The problem is that I don´t know how to cast this char to a boolean type. Does it make sense? Is there other way to do this example in a different way?

Many thanks

Comment: No need to cast. Just check like `if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y') { ... } else { ... }` where `ch` is your `char`

Comment: for starter, don use boolean, use enum

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the way you trying to do is doesn't make scenes. You can do as following

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String st=sc.nextLine();
if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(st)){
  // married
}else if("n".equalsIgnoreCase(st)){
 // not married
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think an enum would be a good way to go.  Encapsulate the rules inside your objects.

Binding user responses to objects is a view responsibility.  Is the input a dropdown or text box?

Marital status is an interesting one.  There are more flavors than "yes/no": single, married, divorced, separated, Kardashian, etc.

```
public class MaritalStatus {
    MARRIED, NOT_MARRIED;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
boolean isYes = (inputChar=='y' || inputChar=='Y');
```

You could also convert the char to upper/lower case so you would not need `||`. Depends on how many tests you have, if it's worth it.

And those parenthesis are not really needed in this case, as `||` has a higher precedence than assignment, but I personally find it clearer when "condition" like that is enclosed in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply cast `char` to `boolean`, but you can compare it to `'y'` and `'n'`

```
public static boolean charToBool(char c) {
    // c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    switch (c) {
        case 'y':
            return true;
        case 'n':
            return false;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be either 'y' or 'n'.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a character into a boolean value, because how should the program know that 'y' means true and 'n' means false?
Use an if statement

```
bool married = false;
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    married = true;
```

I bet a simple google search would have helped you with your homework.